# Error: "Wrong number or types or arguments" when passing array to another procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to pass array as arguement to another procedure..Both are in same package..In this below scenario demo array is passed ..  Getting error : " PLS-00306  wrong number or types of arguments is displayed " ..

```
CREATE or REPLACE package WSH_Delivery_Detail_Shipment is

type Result IS VARRAY(8) OF INTEGER;
p_result Result:=Result();

PROCEDURE CreateShipment(p_delivery_detail_interface_id IN WSH_DEL_DETAILS_INTERFACE.DELIVERY_DETAIL_INTERFACE_ID%TYPE,p_status OUT String);
PROCEDURE CreateShipmentLines(p_result IN RESULT);

END WSH_Delivery_Detail_Shipment;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE package body WSH_Delivery_Detail_Shipment as

PROCEDURE CreateShipment(p_delivery_detail_interface_id IN WSH_DEL_DETAILS_INTERFACE.DELIVERY_DETAIL_INTERFACE_ID%TYPE,p_status OUT String)

IS

CURSOR wddi_cur IS SELECT * FROM WSH_DEL_DETAILS_INTERFACE WHERE DELIVERY_DETAIL_INTERFACE_ID=p_delivery_detail_interface_id;
wddi_record WSH_DEL_DETAILS_INTERFACE%ROWTYPE;

type Result IS VARRAY(8) OF INTEGER;
p_result Result:=Result(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);

BEGIN

OPEN wddi_cur;

LOOP

.. Some few select queries>>>>

WSH_Delivery_Detail_Shipment.CreateShipmentLines(p_result); // Calling procedure and passing array



END LOOP;
CLOSE wddi_cur;
END CreateShipment;

procedure CreateShipmentLines(p_result IN RESULT)

is

BEGIN

....Some select queries

END CreateShipmentLines;
END WSH_Delivery_Detail_Shipment;
/
```

Answer (score 3):

You declared two types named `Result`. `CreateShipmentLines` expects the first one but you are passing the second one.

Removing the second declaration (the line starting '`type Result is ...`' in `CreateShipment`) should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-7C84EBD2-D0A5-4126-8EB7-FF9243EE5B47):

> A collection type defined in a package specification is incompatible with an identically defined local or standalone collection type.

Although in your case both the declarations are within the package, the second one is local to the `CreateShipment` procedure definition, and so is still incompatible with the declaration in the package specification. Although they look the same to you, to the Oracle compiler they are different types.

So as @WilliamRobertson said, you just need to change your procedure to use the type declared in the specification:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package body WSH_Delivery_Detail_Shipment as

PROCEDURE CreateShipment(p_delivery_detail_interface_id IN WSH_DEL_DETAILS_INTERFACE.DELIVERY_DETAIL_INTERFACE_ID%TYPE,p_status OUT String)
IS

  CURSOR wddi_cur IS SELECT * FROM WSH_DEL_DETAILS_INTERFACE WHERE DELIVERY_DETAIL_INTERFACE_ID=p_delivery_detail_interface_id;
  wddi_record WSH_DEL_DETAILS_INTERFACE%ROWTYPE;

  -- type Result IS VARRAY(8) OF INTEGER; -- remove this
  p_result Result:=Result(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1); -- now uses type from specification

BEGIN
  ...
```

As a separate issue, the `p_result Result:=Result();` in the package specification is also completely separate to the `p_result` variable declared in that procedure definition. From what you've shown the global `p_result` is never used, which makes it redundant; but it is also making your package [stateful](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-packages.html#GUID-08E1FC04-9EF3-4396-83C6-4812F8ECABF4), which you probably didn't intend - and that can lead to unnecessary "ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded" errors later. So you probably want to remove that global variable declaration from the specification. (Of course, if you do use that global variable and it's necessary for your package to have state, then ignore this part...)